# Binding to a DoubleAnimation's duration throws TargetInvocationException

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF project using CM. I have a progress bar that I would like to animate smoothly. I have a storyboard containing a DoubleAnimation. The problem is that when I try to bind the Duration of the DoubleAnimation to a property on my view model, I get a TargetInvocationException on running the program.

The XAML for the progress bar looks like this:

```xml
<ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Width="400" Height="18">
    <ProgressBar.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMeasuring}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.Target="{Binding TemplatedParent}" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" 
                                    From="0" 
                                    To="100" 
                                    Duration="{Binding MeasurementDuration}" 
                                />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Style>
</ProgressBar>
```

While the property in my view model looks like this:

```cs
private Duration measurementDuration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
public Duration MeasurementDuration
{
    get { return measurementDuration; }
    private set
    {
        measurementDuration = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MeasurementDuration);
    }
}
```

I feel that the answer is staring straight at me, but I simply cannot find it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know, a binding  to an animation in this implementation way as yours throws always an error.
In the case to change properties of an `Timeline`-Object while it is animated, you have to use the methods `<StoryboardName>.Begin()` to create a new clock for the `Storyboard` and `<StoryboardName>.Seek()` to jump to the reached duration.

Before you call the `<name>.Begin()` method, you change your desired properties and it should work.

Their exists a example in the msdn:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7734

In fact, that in the msdn example "only" the `KeyFrames`-objects of a an `TimeLine`-Object will be changed, you have to call the `Storyboard.Stop()` method before you change the `Duration`-property.

Try it and maybe it helps :)

Kind regards
Sb

Comment: The thing is, I'm not trying to change the duration while the animation is running. What I want to do is set the duration of the animation using the binding and then starting the animation afterwards. This must be possible, but the combinations I've tried have not worked.

Comment: Hey. The exception you got points not to the Duration-Binding. The problem is the Storyboard.TargetName. You are not to allowed to use the Storyboard.TargetName in a style except in a template. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx (#region Animate in a style). Try your solution without setting the Storyboard.TargetName-Property and it should work.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. It works fine with the Storyboard.Target set and a static duration. As soon as I add the duration, it stops working. Thanks for the link though, seems useful.